# Custom tags in xhtml specifying namespace

Tags: javascript, xhtml, namespaces, widget

We have seen in many places that whenever a cross-site widget is imported, it comes with a custom tag with a particular namespace. My question is about how do you declare, use, and modify this in JavaScript.

For example, say Google's +1 button. The import is basically, you import a javascript and then a tag `<g:plusone></g:plusone>` with `g` as the namespace.

I saw their source https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js and find it pretty hard to search how they have defined their namespace in javaScript and imported it.

Basically I want to do three functions.

1. able to define a widget tag `<x:y></x:y>` and parse it using javascript to some dynamic html.
2. This html content will contain dynamic content, animations and ajax calls that will be handled by that single javascript I will be importing.
3. Ability to import multiple widgets on one page everything acting dependently. i.e If I update at one place, the other places gets update.

Comment: I have always thought that in constructions like `<ns:tagname></ns:tagname>`: `ns` is the namespace of our tag, `tagname` is the tag name itself. Clarify that, please.

Comment: sorry for that .. ll modify the question ..

Comment: What's preventing you from just using "x:y" in your code?

Comment: Nothing preventing. My question is how do I declare namespace in JS, Access those elements efficiently as done in many cross-site widgets .

Answer (score 1):

Google namespaced their javascript, but I don't think that is related to the xml tag

I actually just ran across this article not too long ago:
http://www.zachleat.com/web/selecting-xml-with-javascript/
and used Sarissa:
http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/

You could define your own xml tag  and target it with javascript to modify the contents. Also, there is Taconite http://jquery.malsup.com/taconite/ which combined with Sarissa could possibly give you what you are looking for.

As far as namespacing the javascript, you simply need a function or object for scope.

```
var x = {
    y: function (){}
};
```

In this example, y() is namespaced to x, so x.y()